# Runtime test in ISO C for Win10 "Segment Heap"?

Tags: winapi, malloc, heap-memory

Is there a way for an ISO C program to test (maybe an API ?) whether it gets the new Win10 "Segment Heap" (see https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-16/materials/us-16-Yason-Windows-10-Segment-Heap-Internals.pdf) ?

P.S.: The idea is a runtime test, and not peek around in the Win32 registry...

Answer (score 1):

In the slides you linked, the signature is mentioned.

I've verified that checking it as follows indeed works for me:

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    DWORD* sign_ptr = ((DWORD*)GetProcessHeap())+4;
    __try
    {
        DWORD sign = *sign_ptr;
        if (sign == 0xddeeddee) {
            printf("Segmented heap\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Not segmented heap, signature is %08X\n", sign);
        }
    }
    __except (GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION && GetExceptionInformation()->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation[1] == (ULONG_PTR)sign_ptr)
    {
        printf("Bad pointer is %p\n", sign_ptr);
    }
}
```

If I don't enable segmented heap, it prints the following:

```
Not segmented heap, signature is FFEEFFEE
```

I'm not sure if it is officially documented somewhere, and there is another documented way.

I put `__try` block in case if the heap handle is redefined not to be a pointer in a future OS. Perhaps that's not what you call "ISO C" then. You can replace SEH with vectored exception handling, or be brave and skip that part.